# How to Login with a Custom User Model Table in Django 4.1.1?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm making an educational website in Django 4.1.1, and i need students to be able to register and login, so i created a Custom User Model Table in my **models.py** file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager



class Custom(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)


class Student(AbstractUser):

    objects = Custom()

    sex = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='male')
    is_superuser = None
    is_staff = None  
    groups = None
    user_permissions = None


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Student"
        verbose_name_plural = "Students" 


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and then i created an HTML registration  form to get data from the user

```
{% load static %}

<html>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/register.css' %}">
<form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required minlength="3" maxlength="30">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required minlength="3" maxlength="30">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required minlength="3" maxlength="30">
    <small>{{error}}</small>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required maxlength="64">
    <small>{{error}}</small>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required minlength="8" maxlength="32">
    <input type="password" name="passwordAgain" placeholder="Confirm Password" required minlength="8" maxlength="32">
    <small>{{paswword_error}}</small>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male</input>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</input>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
<script src="{% static 'js/register.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

and then i set up my **views.py** file to get the data and store it the database , everything worked well so far .

here is my **view.py** file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Student
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout

# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    # return HttpResponse('This is The Home Page !')
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')






def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        firstName = request.POST['firstName']
        lastName = request.POST['lastName']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        passwordAgain = request.POST['passwordAgain']
        sex = request.POST['sex']
        

        if Student.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or Student.objects.filter(email=email).exists() or password != passwordAgain:
            error = "Alrady Taken"
            paswword_error = "Paswwords Don't Match"
            return render(request,'register/register.html',{'error':error,'paswword_error':paswword_error})
        else:

            user = Student.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.first_name = firstName
            user.last_name = lastName
            user.sex = sex
            user.save()
            return redirect('login')        


        

    
    return render(request,'register/register.html')





def login(request):

    if request.method == 'Post':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('error')

    return render(request, 'login/login.html')
```

the problem is that the Login functionality is not working, it is not working at all , it's not returning anything neither sucess nor errors !

so how can i set up a login functionality that compares the data gotten from the user with the data in the database, and log in the user based on the right match ?

Comment: `request.method == 'Post'` that will never be true, the `method` attribute is guaranteed to be uppercase...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat after i fixed that POST misspelling, whenever i try wrong credentials , the functionality works and throws wrong credentials error , but when i fill in the right credentials i get this error ``` TypeError at /login/
login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  ```

Comment: You do realize your view is also named `login`? You aren't calling `django.contrib.auth.login` when you write `login(request,user)` you're just calling your own view recursively.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you Bro, The Problem is solved, as you said : i was misspelling the post method , iy should be 'POST' rather than Post , and also i was mistakenly naming my login view 'login' same as django.contrib.auth.login

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that i was miss-spelling the `request.method == 'Post'` , it should be `request.method == 'POST'` , the second problem was that i was naming my login view **login**, and that's unacceptable, because that name is already taken by `django.contrib.auth.login`, so i changed the view name , and the problem was solved successfully !